# GRUB command line shows after switching to Windows HDD and back again

Tags: linux, debian, grub2

I installed Debian 8 on my laptop, all went well. I switched the laptop off and back on a few times over a number of days and it booted into the OS fine.

I have since removed the hard drive and used my Windows hard drive for a while.

I have today put the Debian hard drive back in and it will only boot to the GRUB command line and not the OS.

Why? How do I make it boot into the OS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, GRUB is loading at startup, because you swapped out your hard drive.  To correct this, you will have to go [into your BIOS](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-enter-bios-2624481) and reconfigure your boot settings.

Alternatively, if the issue is that you are running headless, try running the command [`startx`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518454/what-does-startx-command-do).

Comment: Reconfigure my boot settings to what? It is setup with the boot device as my hard drive and secure boot is off. Plus what does headless mean?

Comment: Running headless https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647719/what-does-headless-mean means navigating your OS without a graphical interface (i.e. in the command line).  Upon further inspection, it looks like a better solution is to edit `/etc/default/grub` https://askubuntu.com/questions/157925/how-do-i-skip-the-grub-menu-on-a-dual-boot-system